# Emissions reading on a 1993 Toyota Corona/Carina E 3SFE 2.0

Tags: toyota, emissions, corona

Are these values normal for a 1993 car? If not, please tell me what should be fixed or replaced. I believe it's running rich based on the lambda value.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Why does RPM read "0"? Were these just peak values for a given run?

Comment: Thank you! The testing device doesn't read the rpm for some reasons. It's on idle, normal engine operating temperature.

Comment: CO and HC are within the range for UK emissions testing (max 0.20 and 200) but lambda should be 1, not 2. (UK emissions test limits are 0.97 to 1.03) Lambda > 1 means it is running lean, not rich, which is consistent with a lot of oxygen in the exhaust (should be close to zero, not 12%).